# 2 ubuntu servers on a LAN

Tags: server, samba

I have 2 servers on a LAN.  Server a is sharing folders with samba. Is it possible to share a folder from server b in the smb.conf of server a?

[image]

Comment: Can you expand on why you want to do this?  Why can't you share a folder from server B using the `smb.conf` of server B?  I suppose you could "export" a folder in server B and then mount it on server A as an NFS mount.  And then share that using Samba...but this seems like a round-about way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the ansewer. What do you mean by export: copy ? if yes the folder is 1.5 Tb. I would prefer to share it on the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why the client cannot access the share on Server b directly either but to answer your question: Yes you can.

You would have to:

[1] Create a samba share in the smb.conf on Server b.

[2] Mount ( a CIFS mount ) that share on Server a.

[3] Create a share definition in the smb.conf on Server a of the mount point from step [2].

Convoluted and I can't help but think it would be slower than the client accessing Server-b directly but it can be done.

**EDIT**: Ray's comment above is doing the same thing except he is replacing my steps [1] and [2] with the NFS equivalent. That is what his reference to "export" is all about.

Comment: Many thanks  to Ray and Morbius1 for the help. It work perfectly